# Centos 6 FTP problem

Tags: centos, permissions, home, pure-ftpd

I have a VPS running CentOS 6. I've tried multiple FTP servers but the following problem keeps me stuck.

I want all users to have FTP access to their own folder in `/home`, so I configured Pure-FTPd to chroot all users except the `admin` account. This seems to work fine except the following which bugs me:

When I use FileZilla to log in to the `admin` account (not chrooted), it lists `/home/admin`. When I navigate to the root directory, I can browse its files, but when I click back to the `home` folder, it's empty. The `admin` folder is now missing and i have to manually enter `/home/admin` to view the content again.

So basically I cannot view or modify the `home` folder itself.

I'm guessing a permission problem or FTP setting but I cannot find the answer.